# Книги по Prolog

Tags: книги, prolog

Может кто-нибудь посоветовать качественную книгу по языку Prolog, желательно с уклоном в GNU Prolog ?

Comment: Вот есть книга [GNU Prolog](http://almamani.narod.ru/gnu-prolog/gnu-prolog.pdf) на русском языке, собственно, от автора GNU Prolog. Насколько подходит для изучения не могу сказать.

Comment: Спасибо, такая книжка есть у меня на английском, но это немного не то, поскольку для изучения языка с нуля совсем не подходит. Это сухое описание самого интерпретатора, с очень кратким описанием особенностей диалекта.

Comment: Я думаю подойдут любые более-менее свежие книги, не привязанные к Turbo или Visual Prolog. Ну а специфические для GNU Prolog детали можно уточнять в вышеупомянутой книге.

Comment: Вот какие книги можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не читал, но все мои знакомые советуют И. Братко «Алгоритмы искусственного интеллекта на языке Prolog»

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Полистал. Действительно очень хорошая книжка.